# Putting Nomenclature in a table

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

(New to LaTeX) I am recreating a Microsoft Word document in LaTeX and need a list of abbreviations in a table. I am using the `nomencl` package because I like the way I can put entries into the nomenclature as I use them. Is there a way to put the nomenclature (with the `\printnomenclature`) in a table instead of standalone, or another way I can get the desired layout.

Comment: Using `glossaries` seems easier here, in my point of view. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, so I just put the `nomenclature` in a `longtable`, however, this requires some more setup (i.e. getting rid off some features.)

Using `glossaries` and making a new glossary would be much easier and configurable at all!!!!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{nomencl}


\makenomenclature



\nomenclature{CID}{Description}%
\nomenclature{DTM}{Description}%
\nomenclature{FDT}{Description}%
\nomenclature{SDD}{Description}%

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\thenomenclature}{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}%
  {
    \section*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
  }%
  {
    \chapter*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
  }%
}{}{\typeout{Patch success!}}{\typeout{Patch failure!}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\clearpage
\markboth{}{}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
\huge\bfseries \nomname  \tabularnewline
\endfirsthead
\printnomenclature\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}



\end{document}
```