# Table-like list of symbols in Lyx

Tags: lists

How do I create a list of symbols like this in Lyx? I have tried the usual `Nomenclature` with entries, but it's way less "tidy". Any suggestions?

The image is taken from [this](http://www.e-lc.org/dissertations/Documents/1180626678.pdf) thesis.

[image]

Comment: this really has nothing to do with lyx, so i've removed that tag.  if i get some free time, and nobody else has answered it first, i have constructed tables like this using a more manual technique with page numbers provided using a `\label` and `\pageref` mechanism, which allows one to define one's own layour.

Comment: Package `glossaries` might be of use here.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer `nomencl` is native to the GUI of lyx, `glossaries` requires latex coding also known as Evil Red Text (ERT)

Comment: also, this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306439/90297

Comment: @EladDen: For me LyX is the Evil 'Red' Text actually ;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Any chance you would revisit this question? I'm curious to know how to construct such a table myself. :)

Comment: @Troy -- i'll mark it for later attention.  right now i'm trying to put together the slides for my talk at tug 2017.  i don't have the luxury of a working latex system on my laptop, so i can't finish them on the plane like so many speakers claim to do.